# Stack overflow crash when taking out and in widgets from layout

Tags: python, pyside6

I have a method which takes out the widgets from a layout and inserts them back based on the widget position property, but something is wrong because I get `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` which is a stack overflow I think. As you can see, the labels get bugged after shuffling and the program eventually crashes.

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from random import shuffle


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_bars = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.layout_bars)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.number_of_elements = 3

        self.elements = []

        shuffle_button = QPushButton()
        shuffle_button.clicked.connect(self.shuffle_elements)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(shuffle_button)

        self.create_elements()

    def create_elements(self):
        for i in range(self.number_of_elements):
            label = QLabel(f"Label {i}")
            label.position = i
            self.elements.append(label)
            self.layout_bars.addWidget(label)

    def update_elements(self):
        widgets = []
        # Takes out all the widgets from the layout and
        # puts them in a list
        for i in range(self.number_of_elements):
            widgets.append(self.layout_bars.takeAt(0).widget())

        # Adds the widgets back to the layout ordered
        # by their postion property
        for w in widgets:
            self.layout_bars.insertWidget(w.position, w)

    def shuffle_elements(self):
        new_positions = list(range(self.number_of_elements))
        shuffle(new_positions)
        for index, position in enumerate(new_positions):
            self.elements[index].position = position
            print(position)
        self.update_elements()


app = QApplication([])
window = Widget()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Done @eyllanesc

Answer (score 1):

Before setting it in the layout you must remove the parent from the widget:

```py
def update_elements(self):
    widgets = []
    # Takes out all the widgets from the layout and
    # puts them in a list
    for i in range(self.number_of_elements):
        widget = self.layout_bars.takeAt(0).widget()
        widget.setParent(None) # <---
        widgets.append(widget)

    # Adds the widgets back to the layout ordered
    # by their postion property
    for w in widgets:
        self.layout_bars.insertWidget(w.position, w)
```

Comment: Why do I have to do this? The widgets are going to get the same parent again, right?

Comment: @PepeElMago33 It seems that Qt does not verify that (maybe a bug) so it tries to eliminate it causing a *segmentation fault*.

Comment: Sorry but you solution does not work, it keeps crashing

Comment: @PepeElMago33 It works for me, I recommend running your script from the console (don't use an IDE) so that you get a more descriptive error message

Comment: Which PySide version are you using? I'm using Python 3.10 and PySide 6.2. Yes i'm running it from terminal, I know that pycharm can hide errors but this is not the case

Comment: Yes It does not work in PySide6 but it does in PySide2, I've reported an issue https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1683